# Why is Blender not saving my render after I already set the output location?

Tags: rendering

Why is Blender not saving my render after I already set the output location
This seems to be themost common problem I see in all the forums Ive read so far, yet after doing it, its still not saving anything?
I do Render>Render image and see the render in blender but its not in the folder I specified

Comment: Because path is for animation. If you want to save still image render you can enable addon Auto Save Render that save it automatically or you can set animation as one frame or you can enable Compositor and add "File Output" node or you have to go to Image editor and save render manually. BTW if you visited so many forum no answer on the way?

Comment: Is that the official name? Cant seem to find this add on

Comment: And yes I tried the animation but that only renders the current view layer, I have multiple view layers and that doesnt work

Comment: I edited linked answer addon is in Experimental (daily) builds. For official release you have to download from here https://developer.blender.org/F9922136 and install

Comment: @jin098 Multiple view layers? You didn’t mention that in the question. That’s a separate issue altogether.